# Get groups of idling times, BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to get groups of idling times, where `speed` is 0 and there is minimum two such consecutive records, i.e.:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|      min time       |      max time       | idle |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 2017-01-31 23:59:43 | 2017-01-31 23:59:53 |   10 |
| 2017-01-31 23:58:13 | 2017-01-31 23:58:53 |   40 |
| 2017-01-31 23:56:18 | 2017-01-31 23:57:03 |   45 |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```

ideally with totals of idling times in seconds.

Data sample:

```
+-------+-------------------------+
| speed |        datetime         |
+-------+-------------------------+
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:59:53 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:59:43 UTC |
| 0.05  | 2017-01-31 23:59:33 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:59:23 UTC |
| 0.02  | 2017-01-31 23:59:13 UTC |
| 0.02  | 2017-01-31 23:59:03 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:58:53 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:58:43 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:58:33 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:58:23 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:58:13 UTC |
| 0.02  | 2017-01-31 23:58:03 UTC |
| 0.02  | 2017-01-31 23:57:53 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:57:43 UTC |
| 0.02  | 2017-01-31 23:57:33 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:57:23 UTC |
| 0.02  | 2017-01-31 23:57:22 UTC |
| 0.02  | 2017-01-31 23:57:13 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:57:09 UTC |
| 0.02  | 2017-01-31 23:57:08 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:57:03 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:56:53 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:56:51 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:56:43 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:56:34 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:56:33 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:56:23 UTC |
| 0     | 2017-01-31 23:56:18 UTC |
+-------+-------------------------+
```

Query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
 MIN(datetime), MAX(datetime)
FROM
 (SELECT t.*, 
   (SELECT 
     COUNT(*)
    FROM
     `dbtest.log_*` t2
    WHERE
     t2.datetime <= t.datetime and t2.speed > 0) grp
 FROM
 `dbtest.log_*` t
 WHERE t.speed = 0) x
 GROUP BY grp
```

Result:

> "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an
>   equality of fields from both sides of the join."

1. What's wrong with my query?
2. Id there a better way to achieve that in `bigquery`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by groups of idling times? What is the expected output for that input?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  MIN(datetime) AS min_time,
  MAX(datetime) AS max_time,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(datetime), MIN(datetime), SECOND) AS idle
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(speed) OVER(ORDER BY datetime) AS grp
  FROM `dbtest.YourTable`
)
WHERE speed = 0
GROUP BY grp
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
-- ORDER BY grp DESC
```

You can play/test with dummy data in example from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 0 AS speed, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:59:53 UTC' AS datetime UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:59:43 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.05, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:59:33 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:59:23 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:59:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:59:03 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:58:53 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:58:43 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:58:33 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:58:23 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:58:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:58:03 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:53 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:43 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:33 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:23 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:22 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:09 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:08 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:57:03 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:56:53 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:56:51 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:56:43 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:56:34 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:56:33 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:56:23 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, TIMESTAMP '2017-01-31 23:56:18 UTC'
)
SELECT
  MIN(datetime) AS min_time,
  MAX(datetime) AS max_time,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(datetime), MIN(datetime), SECOND) AS idle
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(speed) OVER(ORDER BY datetime) AS grp
  FROM yourTable
)
WHERE speed = 0
GROUP BY grp
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
-- ORDER BY grp DESC
```